# how to apply filter in list using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make a demo application. In which I have **few categories** example like  **Watches, Jeans, etc**

I want to apply filter when I click on any category. In other words I want to show products that of selected category.

here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-meadow-v2flk?file=/src/App.js)

Steps

1. Initially all items are displayed
2. when I apply filter **Sports Shoes** it shows only **two item**.
3. but **my issue is I am iteration in whole list** every time. Is there any better way?

   ```
    useEffect(() => {        
      let fArr = state.filter(i => filterArray.indexOf(i.category) != -1);
       setProductState(fArr);
    }, [filterArray]);
   ```

**any filter selected**

```
const onItemClickHandler = item => {
    setFilterArray([...filterArray, item]);
};
```

**bug or any better approach**

whenever I am applying any filter  **I am iteration whole list again and again** any better approach. Actually currently I have only **100** products.let take it it is **100,000** products I will iterate again and again in **100,000**.

any better approach ?

Comment: Store a "Current search" and when you add a new filter, only search that smaller list? (This assumes the filters narrow down the results, rather than add to them. And doesn't help when removing a filter, but certainly speeds things up in one direction)

Comment: If you have a large set of data, its best to get the filtered result from server, however if for some reason you can't you need to memoize your result, so that its calculated only once from each filter if the data remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than thousands data, it's better to map all your data by group, then you only need to use key to retrieve them.

Map data by category:

```
var data = filterArray.reduce((x,v) => {
    (x[v.category] = x[v.category] || []).push(v)
    return x
}, {});
```

If you select the category, you can get the data faster

```
var result = data[category_key];
```